# Extract relevant sections or paragraphs from a document based on keyword

Tags: java, elasticsearch, machine-learning, stanford-nlp, jackrabbit

In one of the project we have some html files stored in oracle database but **we may keep it in files as well or if more appropriate in some NOSQL database whichever is appropriate**. We are given some keywords and based on them we need to find relevant sections in those files. These files are basic company declaration, news articles , financial reports, etc. Now need to find different sections let's say pertaining to below categories:

- **Risk** using keywords like crime, theft, litigation,accuse, etc
- **High rank Changes** using keywords like 'will be leaving', Appointment of   Certain Officers', 'Election of Director', etc
- **Shareholder Rights** using keywords like 'shareholder rights','shareholder lawsuits', 'financial restatements', etc

There are other categories as well and they have defined keywords to  be searched. So the requirement is to ***category-wise* extract the section/paragraph which are *MOST* relevant.** 
The emphasis is on **High accuracy to find most relevant section**.
If technologies like *Solr or Elastic search or Jackrabbit* provides that we are open. Just need right direction to correct tech-stack needed here.

Currently we are trying [Oracle text search](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/toc.htm) but I believe we might have a better programmatic solution as well may using Machine learning or NLP or some library in Java which would do that. Kindly give me some insights. I am an experienced java developer and working with Machine leaning and NLP. I am language-agnostic, so a good solution using any language or technique is welcome.

Comment: If you have your data in an Oracle database Text that will get you an awfully long way down the road. Learn to use the lexer features and tailor the thesaurus. The big advantage is that you're working with the data in situ using functionality your organization has already paid for.

Comment: @APC - We are open for new technologies. Oracle Text search AFAIK just provides relevance score among different documents NOT within different sections/paragraphs of the document. Also I believe Java-based solution would be available in open source community and be already serving this functionality just wanted to know the which one and how to kick off.

Answer (score 0):

The direction you seem to be going with this question is one of word/phrase search [easy] vs semantic search [hard].  There have been several people over the years to work on such solutions [I met folks from a company in Scotland who were building a Java based solution, but I can't recall the name].  Where you get into trouble with semantic search is that there are so many problem domains [and very relevant taxonomies within the domain] where semantics are way different for same words or phrases.  Then of course some folks make the "semantic" job easier by meta-tagging the data (examples: images, video, complex documents), then searching the meta data.

When I was an Enterprise Architect a few years back, we used Verity to essentially Google the enterprise.  I have no idea if it is still a product, but it leveraged Oracle Text and layered it's code on that.

Back in the day, the state of the art was what Forester Research called: "Connecting Data, Content, And Text With Organic Information Abstraction", but I don't know where the state of the practice is right now.

I'll bet Google might have some tools you could use :) .

Sounds like a fun project!!!

Comment: Verity got taken over by Autonomy.  Subsequently HP bought by Autonomy for a controversially high price. The resulting kerfuffle led to investigations and resignations, and who knows whether the products are still in use?